# Whatsapp notification listening

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am working on a app which only shows WhatsApp notification. the problem that I am facing is that it is  showing multiple notifications of the same user. I want to know if the user name is the same, update the notification and save also the previous in a list.

Comment: Where is your MVCE ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What you have done? post code,